# Add date to mysql from php for sorting later

Tags: php, mysql, date

when inserting a date into a MySQL DB using PHP what is the best format so that I can sort by date later. I started using

```
$current_time = date("Y-m-d");
```

Is this the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to control your database fields then I would recommend using MySQL's built in Timestamp data type. You can set it to the current time by default.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `your_table` (
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If not then I would reccomend just storing the default PHP Unix formatted timestamp in an integer field.

```
$current_time = time();
```

Answer (score 1):

The database handles dates internally for storing and sorting. Y-m-d format is good

Answer (score 0):

You do not ever need to generate the current date or time in PHP to insert it into a query. Use the MySQL constants CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the query instead.

```
INSERT INTO table (name, date) VALUES ('Bob', CURRENT_DATE)
```