# save Date Number in PHP variable

Tags: php

This question goes [along with another one of my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500786/format-date-number-from-database) that I already accepted

How do I get the "date number" in php

```
2010-08-24 20:00:00.000
```

I want to assign the current date number to a variable $current_date_num so I can use it in my query to compare what is already in the database.

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE [Room_ID] = '$field' AND [Meeting Start] > '$current_date_num' ORDER BY [Meeting Start] asc ";
```

Comment: "another one of my post" do you mean this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457543/add-date-to-mysql-from-php-for-sorting-later? Can you link please

Comment: actually its http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500786/format-date-number-from-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using it in the database, consider [NOW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

Comment: I am only using it to compare a data number in a database.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current date number in the format above you would do:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s.u")
```

Comment: If I do it this way is it a string? I should be able to compare it to other dates that are in the database in the same format correct.

Comment: Yes it will be a string.  How exactly are you comparing?  When you compare dates in php, you usually want to use strotime() for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can get the date number like this.. ex. from php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
    $today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
    $today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
    $today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
    $today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
    $today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
    $today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
    $today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
    $today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$current_date_num  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", time());`

refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to specify it in the page from user side
use it this way

```
 strtotime($time1)
```